# Firebase Authentication connect Email with Phone

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am currently using **Email** and **Phone number** authentication using Firebase.

And i have **3** EditText for:

- Email
- Phone Number
- Password

But the problem is when the user is done registering it obviously creates **2** instance of accounts, one for the **Email** and second for the **Phone number**.

I would like to link the **Email** and **Phone number** together as one account. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Did you get any solution? I am facing the same issue.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Depending on whether you want to allow for signing in with either email or phone number, or if you want to allow for the Phone number to be used as a second factor, for sign in, there are different solutions.

If you just want to have the Phone number **be a second way to sign in**, you can link the credentials using the `linkWithCredential` method on your Firebase User. This way you can add as many ways to sign in, as you want. Firebase has a [good guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/account-linking) on this.

If you want the phone number to `be a second factor of authentication`, you will need to have a custom auth provider, which does the second factor authentication. There is also a [getting started guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/custom-auth) on this, however the 2 Factor Authentication part itself would be up to you.

Comment: Can you show us code with whole answer - first sign up with email, then do the phone auth and put it into the same userid (without creating a new user id)... I am having some issue with PhoneAuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(VerificationId, code);