# Firebase Secondary Authentication with Phone Number

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

In my Android app, there is a user setting where the user can enable 2-Factor Authentication. And I am using Firebase Email/Authentication.

So once after successful login, if 2-Factor Authentication enabled user needs to get some PIN to their registered mobile numbers to proceed further to the app.

Through the doc [Authenticate with Firebase on Android using a Phone Number](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth) I could see a way to log in with Phone Number.

But how to integrate this with Email/Password Authentication. I need better guidance on this.

Comment: do u want to link the authentications? https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/account-linking

Comment: @PeterHaddad, After email/password authentication, Firebase should send OTP to sign in for secondary authentication

Comment: Firebase Auth does not currently support multi-factor authentication. They currently allow linking multiple providers including phone number which allows you to sign in with either provider to the same account but only one factor is needed to do so.

Comment: @bojeil Is there any tweak to do this firebase? I just want the Firebase to send OTP? Rest I can handle. Is there a way?

Answer (score 1):

Found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44689507/3846715) by @Bernd

If you want the phone number to be the second factor of authentication, you will need to have a **custom auth provider**, which does the second-factor authentication. There is also a [getting started guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/custom-auth) on this, however, the 2 Factor Authentication part itself would be up to you.

Answer (score 1):

Why not combine them and use [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences) to monitor the states?

You should be able to store any of three values in a SharedPreferences: SIGNED_OUT, PENDING, SIGNED_IN.

This is my suggestion flow:

- When the user is not signed in, the value in the SharedPreferences reference should be **SIGNED_OUT**.
- User signs in with email-password.. if successful, **PENDING** is saved in SharedPreferences; this means that the user isn't fully authenticated yet. Due to this value, the MainActivity (or it's equivalent) is never shown.
- The user is prompted to sign in with phone number. If this is successful, the value in SharedPreferences is once again changed to **SIGNED_IN**, this denotes that the user has been signed in fully.

To smoothen the flow, a service can be used to reset the value of the  SharedPreferences reference from PENDING to SIGNED_OUT if the auth state has not changed after a period of time (say 10 minutes).

I hope this helps. Merry coding!