# How to allow email id to receive OTP in firebase for authentication

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am developing an app wherein the users use either email and phone to perform registration.

Users can enter their email or phone for log in, I want the same OTP to be sent to mobile and email simultaneously. Please Help!

Comment: Please check this link on how to ask questions in StackOverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask  show what you have tried, what is failing, add code snippets etc.

Comment: OTP verification through SMS is straightforward and so is email verification link. OP asked how to send OTP to email along with SMS. @Gerardo

Comment: may be [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44677846/2289835) can help.

Comment: not possible with firebase auth otp verification .

Answer (score 4):

If you want to work only with [Firebase Authentication,](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/) then there is **not any suitable solution** that meets your requirement.

Some limitations you can find with *Firebase* are [Firebase Authentication Limits](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/limits) and [Phone number sign-in limits.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/limits#phone_number_sign-in_limits)

However the alternative solution is using third-party SMS gateway. through with you can send OTP to phone number as well as to email also simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume you already have mechanism to generate OTP and verify OTP from android app.

Now the problem is how to send OTP to the user's email.
One of solution is using `MailGun` service to send email from your backend.

Also, if you want to templating your email, you can use library called `handlebar`

Comment: I want the same OTP to be sent to mobile and email simultaneously.

Comment: if you mean OTP from firebase phone auth, then we cannot send it to user's email, because it's firebase privilege and we cannot mess with it.