# How to allow user to login Using Mobile number or email id using firebase in Edittext

Tags: android, firebase

Allow user to login via email id or mobile number using `Firebase` ,like two way login both should work with same password.

Comment: Check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44677846/firebase-authentication-connect-email-with-phone

Comment: you have two databases in firebase realtime and firestore which one are you using??

Answer (score 1):

If you are referring to the login parameters that need to be validated on the Firebase you can modify the rules for that particular app. Or Referring to the Firebase database, you can have three fields and validate them.

Comment: Yes referring to login parameters , how to modify.