# How to allow user to sign in with both email +password and with mobile number+password with Firebase IOS

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am trying to make the following things:

- Sign in with number and password. (Connect email/number)
- Use one textfield for email/ number when the user can type one of the options and firebase will login in to that user account

I looked up at Firebase docs but there was not no mention about having **Phone Number / Password** auth.

For example, I signed up: email: SOME_MAIl password: SOME_PASSWORD number: SOME_NUMBER I want to make something like this

```
If numberAuth {
 Auth.auth.signIn(withNumber: number, password: password ) 
} else { 
Auth.auth.signIn(email: email, password: password ) }
```

I found out that I have to customize firebase auth but I don't have an idea how to custom that. How that should be done?

P.S.: My idea is similar to this question  [Firebase Authentication connect Email with Phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44677846/firebase-authentication-connect-email-with-phone)

In the image below the idea is illustrated

Here is my code:

```
 func signIn() {
   
       
    if let password = passwordValue.text, let email = emailValue.text {
        Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password  ) { [weak self] authResult, error in
            if let e = error {
                print(e)
                let alert = Service.createAlertController(title: "Error", message: e.localizedDescription)
                self?.present(alert, animated: true,completion: nil)
            } else {
                let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
                let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(identifier: "main")
                vc.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen
                self?.present(vc, animated: true)
                
            }
        }
    }
    
    
}
```

[image]

Comment: I am not really sure what you're asking; the code in the question is email authentication. What are you trying to do beyond that, and do you have some code you've attempted we can take a look at?

Comment: So, I want to make email + password auth and phone + password auth. The user enter either number or email in first textfield. I want to customize my func with email auth. I looked up in firebase documentation there is nothing more about this case that I want to do.  The idea what I want to is similar to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44677846/firebase-authentication-connect-email-with-phone

Comment: Isn't this just a matter of evaluating what the user entered? If it's an email, then use email authentication, of it parses to a phone number, use that. Right?

Comment: @Jay yes, I can add some if else for that, but there would happen duplicate numbers in firebase database. 1 number would be in 2 different users. 


For example, I signed up:

email: SOME_MAIl
password: SOME_PASSWORD
number: SOME_NUMBER

I want to make something like this 
If numberAuth { Auth.auth.signIn(withNumber: number, password: password ) }
else { Auth.auth.signIn(email: email, password: password ) }

Comment: Firebase authentication doesn't allow duplicate emails or numbers and will throw an error in those situations right up front so you can notify the user. So this... *1 number would be in 2 different users* ...can't actually happen.

Comment: so let me then show you that is is possible. follow this link to see 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KswVsnu_WRT1m_1XYzeH0zZDu40bSrLF/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Please don't post links - that one requires authentication so it's not useful. Firebase Authentication does not allow duplicate emails; if you attempt to use a duplicate email, firebase will return an "emailAlreadyInUse" error - here are the error code [emailAlreadyInUse](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebaseauth/api/reference/Enums/AuthErrorCode#emailalreadyinuse)

Comment: I provided you info that 1 phone numbers have duplicates and now you are still arguing. It is just drive link, not something bad.